# Positioning an element using values from Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, html

How to position an element for e.g. a `div` tag by using values for `x` & `y` co-ordinates from Javascript variables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to position the object in absolute x,y coordinates on the page, just set the object to position: absolute and then set the values of top and left to your x and y.

HTML:

```
<div id="square" style="background-color: #777; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
```

Code:

```
var s = document.getElementById("square");
s.style.position = "absolute";
var x = 100, y = 200;
s.style.left = x + "px";
s.style.top = y + "px";
```

You can see a working code example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hhpDQ/.

Comment: how do I set the values from JS to element's attribute? Code samples please if possible..

Comment: Thank you for the (+"px") I would never figure out this without your post. Congratulation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can set the coordinates, but you could set the margin. Something like

```
$("#divid").css("margin-left" : "200px" , "margin-up" : "200px");
```

Comment: Do note that this example uses the jQuery javascript librar